# C: printf is not printing the answer to the input by user

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I have a code that if the user key in "what is apple" it should answer "apple is a fruits" but for this case 
the what is stored as [what] in a text file. Look like this

```
[what]
apple = apple is a fruits.
```

below is my codes. It doesnt print out " apple is a fruits". Can i know where is my error?

```
char intent[255];
char key1[255];
char key[255];
char inv[3][10] = { "what","where","who" };

snprintf(intent, sizeof(intent), "[%s]", inv[0]);
printf("%s\n", intent);

scanf("%s",&key1);

if (strcmp (intent == "[what]" && key == "apple") == key1) {
    printf ("apple is a fruits");
    }
```

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in C.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/charstring/stringeq.html

Comment: Hi, I have edited the codes but it doesnt work and there is error " Access violation reading location 0x00000000 "

Comment: The code as modified should not compile — `strcmp()` requires two arguments, and you provide just one.  You should be using `strcmp(intent, "[what]") == 0 && strcmp(key, "apple") == 0` as the condition to compare two pairs of strings.

Comment: You should learn from a reference, rather than trial and error

Comment: There are other issues with your code that will cause it to not run as intended. The usage of & in scanf and the misuse of snprintf. Check my response for more

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn said in his comment to your question, you can't compare C strings using the == operator, you need to use the strcmp() function.

Also, the second parameter of snprintf should be the number of chars that should not be exceeded by the function, which isn't what sizeof(intent) does. sizeof(intent) wouldn't give you the size of the intent array, but return the size of a char* pointer, if I'm correct.
Just replace sizeof(intent) with 255 or use a constant MAXSIZE for it.

Also, scanf doesn't need the & operator when writing to char arrays (ie strings), `scanf("%s", key1);` is correct, as the name of an array *is* the address.

Comment: In this case since `intent` is an array, not a pointer, `sizeof(intent)` is 255 and using it is appropriate.